# SharePoint 2013 autohosted app: Access/Edit the webconfig after deployment

Tags: sharepoint-addin, web-config, autohosted

I would like to know if there is the possibility to access the web-config of my autohosted app after it has been deployed. I want to do this for changing some key values e.g. Logging = "False".

Is there any way you can access those self deployed files of the app? I can't find any documentation for the subject on msdn.